# for-loops (how can i get it to ignore some parts if need be)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
def reporta():
    with open("userinfo.txt","r") as f:
        text = [line.strip() for line in f]
        ulist = [x.split(",") for x in text]
    for n in range(len(ulist)):
        uname = input("Which username do you want to see?\n")
        if uname == ulist[n][0]:
            print("The username is",ulist[n][0],"\nThe user's password is",ulist[n][1],"\nThe user's name is",
                  ulist[n][2],"\nThe user's age is",ulist[n][3],"\nThe user's year group is",ulist[n][4])
            for i in range (5,11):
                if i == 5:
                    if ulist[n][i] == "-1":
                        print("Maths easy has not been taken by",ulist[n][0])
                    else:
                        print(ulist[n][0],"got",ulist[n][i])
                elif i == 6:
                    if ulist[n][i] == "-1":
                        print("Maths medium has not been taken by",ulist[n][0])
                    else:
                        print(ulist[n][0],"got",ulist[n][i])
                elif i == 7:
                    if ulist[n][i] == "-1":
                        print("Maths hard has not been taken by",ulist[n][0])
                    else:
                        print(ulist[n][0],"got",ulist[n][i])
                elif i == 8:
                    if ulist[n][i] == "-1":
                        print("History easy has not been taken by",ulist[n][0])
                    else:
                        print(ulist[n][0],"got",ulist[n][i])
                elif i == 9:
                    if ulist[n][i] == "-1":
                        print("History medium has not been taken by",ulist[n][0])
                    else:
                        print(ulist[n][0],"got",ulist[n][i])
                else:
                    if ulist[n][i] == "-1":
                        print("History hard has not been taken by",ulist[n][0])
                    else:
                        print(ulist[n][0],"got",ulist[n][i])
            break
```

In this piece of code, i am attempting to print things from a file according to which username is inputted, however, if i try to input a username on the second or third row of the list, i have to input the username two or three times before it recognises it. What am i not including/doing wrong?

Example:

```
file contains:
aad15,arbiter,aadam,15,11,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
jam11,jammy,james,11,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
ton15,tonehh,tony,15,11,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
mas15,radicallx,mash,15,11,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
```

If i input aad15 as a username, it runs the program as it is supposed to. If i input jam11, i have to input it twice before it does what its supposed to do. If i put ton15 in i have to input it three times before it does what its supposed to do and so on.

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I don't really know how to phrase this questions @pvg

Comment: You included the `input()` in the loop which runs over the entries so it asks on each entry until it finds the desired one.

Comment: "rest is indented I'm just lazy". This is bad behavior here. You should show your effort to solve the problem and to write the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple: you have your input line within the loop and thus it is requesting user input on every pass of the loop. Move `uname = input("Which username do you want to see?\n")` to the line above `for n in range(len(ulist)):`

However, as [@pvg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5087125/pvg) says, please review the guidelines on [using examples when asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, I will go look at the guidelines now